# How to handle updating an AWS EC2 instances AMI?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

on my aws setup I have load balances pointing to several app servers which all use a common API. The app servers all have the same NGINX cong (nginx.conf) which for various reasons I now need to update.

What's the way to handle this? Do I update the AMI and relaunch the app servers? Do I have to relaunch the servers? Is there a way to update the AMI and leave the servers running?

I'm desperately looking for a tutorial/best-practice on how to handle this situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) will do the job. Or you can roll your own via a simple shell script and `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

While chef and puppet is the right way to do it, but if you don't want to get into that kind of stuff, you can do it with just a couple of steps.

1. Make an AMI of one of your load balanced instance (DO NOT Select Reboot) while making your AMI.
2. Make an instance from that AMI, make the changes in it, and test this instance, Make AMI from this Instance.

Now the trick is to make your instances go bad, so that load balancer feels that it has gone bad and creates a new machine to replace the bad instance; but why would it like to maintain a new instance, it won't unless you specify to the load balancer how many instances it should have at minimum, now there is no config to do so, because its not a part of load balancer's profile, its the scaling policy.

so make an autoscaling policy (with the new AMI) off-course and make a new launch config (with the new ami offcourse), set minimum number of instances to whatever number you want, lets say 2 (always try to keep a couple, and whenever scale up/down keep it a couple of instances).

now go ahead and reduce the health check of LB, SSH into one of your instance (stop the nginx), the LB will think it has gone bad and launch config to keep min. number of instances will kick off, bringing in a new instance with the new AMI.